# Using TAL language to find info by user in Plone

Tags: plone, zope

I've installed collective.portlet.tal.
My goal is to show for each user, his info in his own folder by this portlet.
Fox example now I want to show: username and email.

By default I have this portlet that show nothing of special:

```
<dl class="portlet portlet${portlet_type_name}"
tal:define="portal_state context/@@plone_portal_state;
            context_state context/@@plone_context_state;">

<dt class="portletHeader">
    <span class="portletTopLeft"></span>
    <span>
       Header
    </span>
    <span class="portletTopRight"></span>
</dt>

<dd class="portletItem odd">
    Body text
</dd>

<dd class="portletFooter">
    <span class="portletBotomLeft"></span>
    <span>
       Footer
    </span>
    <span class="portletBottomRight"></span>
</dd>
```

I've inserted in the Body this line to get the username of the folder, but it returns the name of the visitor. If I'm the admin, it will show "admin", or if I'm a member, it will show the member's name...and so on.

```
<p tal:content="user/getUserName"></p>
```

How can I show the creator of that folder?
How can is possible get the emailof that user for that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `Creator` of your folder:

```
<p tal:define="creator context/Creator;
               mtool context/@@plone_tools/membership;
               author python:mtool.getMemberInfo(creator)"
   tal:content="python:author and author['fullname'] or creator">Author name</p>
```

The above snippet looks up the creator userid (this defaults to the owner of the content object), and uses the membership tool to look up a member info object for that user. We then display the user's full name, or if the creator is not a Plone user, just the userid.

Comment: I've tried your code in the body section, but is not showing nothing, just blank space, despite I'm in a member folder and I should see "author_name".
What's wrong?

Comment: Your `Creator` entry is empty; check on the `edit` tab to confirm. How do you set ownership of the folders?

Comment: My creator tab has the name of the creator, in this case the correct username and seems to be ok.
The folder is create when a user login for the first time, I've set this option in Plone.

Comment: Interesting; does `context/listCreators` display anything in the portlet?

Comment: @user840718: then `context/Creator` should work too, in which case the `fullname` for the author is empty. I'll update the answer to use the creator id instead.

Comment: Well now is working with context/Creator!
So to get fields like email, address and other, what can I do?

Comment: @user840718: the member info object holds all that; use `author.getProperty(propertyname)`. Some of these have shortcuts (like fullname), but `getProperty` returns anything you defined as a member property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16920/discussion-between-user840718-and-martijn-pieters)